# xamarin collectionview cell custom border

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, border, collectionview

How to add custom border to the collectionview cell like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBgO2.jpg)?

```
   <CollectionView HeightRequest="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout >
                                <GridItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Span="4"/>
                                
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid >
                                            <Image  Source="{Binding Image}" ></Image>
                                        </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the collection view into a colored `container` could do that, and set `margin` for the collection view as the width of border, like

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<CollectionView Margin="4,0">
</CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a sub-class frame to add border, please take a look at the following code:

Creating custom frame in .Net standard library project(shared code).

```
public class MyFrame : Xamarin.Forms.Frame
{
  
}
```

Custom renderer in Android platform.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyFrame), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
 namespace demo3.Droid
{
[Obsolete]
class MyFrameRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Frame>
{
    public MyFrameRenderer()
    {
        SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.blue_rect));
    }
}
}

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <control:MyFrame Padding="5">

            <CollectionView BackgroundColor="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" />

                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Gray">

                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black" />

                        </Frame>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>


        </control:MyFrame>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The screenshot:

[image]